# Close a popup window

Tags: jquery, popup

I start to learn jQuery. I create a popup window and add a button on it. I want to click on that button to close my popup window, I use an id to attach my window, but it is not working. Thank you for your help.

```
<a href="" rel="0" class="patrick" >click me</a>

var windowSizeArray = ["width=200,height=200", "width=3000,height=400,scrollbars=yes"];

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#win').bind('click', function () {
        newwindow.close();
    });
    var $newdiv1 = $('<input type="button" class="myButton" value="ok" id="win"/>')

    $('.patrick').click(function (event) {
        var url = $(this).attr("href");
        var windowName = "popUp"; //$(this).attr("name");
        var windowSize = windowSizeArray[$(this).attr("rel")];

        var newwindow = window.open(url, windowName, windowSize);
        event.preventDefault();
        $(newwindow.document.body).html($newdiv1);
    });


});
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use inline JS much, but in this case, just adding some inline JS to the button is the easiest solution :

```
var windowSizeArray = ["width=200,height=200", "width=3000,height=400,scrollbars=yes"];

$(document).ready(function () {
    var $newdiv1 = $('<input type="button" class="myButton" value="ok" id="win" onclick="window.close()"/>')

    $('.patrick').click(function (event) {
        var url = $(this).attr("href");
        var windowName = "popUp"; //$(this).attr("name");
        var windowSize = windowSizeArray[$(this).attr("rel")];

        var newwindow = window.open(url, windowName, windowSize);
        event.preventDefault();
        $(newwindow.document.body).html($newdiv1);
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/9hJEn/)